# Attempting to change a current Java function to comply with a Fortify scan recommendation

Tags: java, datasource, fortify

I'm currently in the process of cleaning up and correcting code reported as High/Low by a Fortify scan.  I'm stuck on the following, which calls for releasing resources in a finally block.

Below is what I have currently:

```
public static Hashtable<String, Boolean> getUserACLPermission(String akoId) {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Hashtable<String, Boolean> returnValue = new Hashtable<String, Boolean>();
    try {
        DataSource ds = getDataSource();
        if (ds != null) {
            connection = ds.getConnection();
            ps = connection
                    .prepareStatement(ApplicationConstants.ACL_GENERIC_QUERY);
            ps.setString(1, akoId);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                returnValue.put(rs.getString(1), new Boolean(true));
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
        ne.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            safeClosePS(ps);
            }
        if (rs != null) {
            safeCloseRS(rs);
            }
        if (connection != null) {
            safeCloseConn(connection);
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

And this is what Fortify is recommending:

```
public void execCxnSql(Connection conn) {
    Statement stmt;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(CXN_SQL);
      ...
    }
    finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            safeClose(stmt);
        }
    }
}
public static void safeClose(Statement stmt) {
    if (stmt != null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried a different variation on this and re-scanned, but getting the same results.  Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you are using java 7+?  There they added [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) that was added just for this.

Comment: I prefer try-with resources here too. Close Resultset before PreparedStatement. The first return is redundant; remove it.

Comment: Unfortunately no, still on java 6 for now, but will be upgrading soon.

Answer (score 0):

'I think' Fortify is expecting that akoId is validated before using. The it won't tell you the exact error. Errors seems to be misleading.